# Get commit id of a directory

Tags: git

I have a directory on the production server which was deployed some time ago. On the development server, I developed much more and pushed it to git.

Is there a way to check the current commit id of the directory on the production server, just to make sure (through cli)?

Something like, I run: `git check current-commit-id` on the directory (on production server) so I get the current commit id of that directory. And if something bad happens, I can go back to that working version

Update: Using `git rev-parse HEAD`, it gives me "777dc337c212095cfda279bef882d3266b0f123"; instead I want the one that looks like "9be5922"

Comment: Directories don't have commit IDs. Only commits have commit IDs. If you have a Git repository, it's full of commits, each of which has a commit ID. If the production server has a repository, you can compare its work-tree to some commit, and if those are the same, you can use the commit ID of that commit as a proxy for the work-tree, but of course this doesn't tell you anything about untracked files (including untracked-and-ignored files). If that's what you mean, run `git status`, see if thinks look good, and then use `git rev-parse HEAD` to get the commit hash for the `HEAD` commit.

Comment: `then use git rev-parse HEAD to get the commit hash for the HEAD commit.` - does that mean `git rev-parse HEAD` will give me the latest pulled commit on that repository? Using this gives me a hashed version, not the commit id. I think it should look like "9be5922" instead of "777dc337c212095cfda279bef882d3266b0f123"

Comment: This long hash is the real commit if also called sha1. What you have is just an abbreviated version (which is nearly every time enough). Take the first 7 characters if you want but since you have all it's preferable to use that... Also, you should perhaps read a little to understand what is a commit id/sha1 in git.......

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For CLI, use:

```
git log HEAD~2..HEAD
```

will show you the last few commits, including their full SHA-1 hashes (i.e. commit ID). You can change the `~2` to another number to see a specific number of commits.

And using:

```
git log
```

will list all of them, for the current branch.  If that is `master`, the last entry should be the first commit when you started the repo.

---

***Note:** Edited to remove superfluous items resolving with the OP what the real question was (see comments)*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But I think you understood me wrong (because I don't know much of terminology). Think about that: I have a repository on git, and I pulled it to server a few months ago. Now I went into server, and want to know the commit-id when I pulled it there few months ago, so if anything crashes, I can go revert back to that commit.

Comment: That's the equivalent of looking at the entire commit history, and finding the first one - in Git Extensions (still recommended), just scroll all the way to the bottom of the list and click on the first commit to get all the details on it, look at the files at the time of that commit, etc.  If you want to list the entire log from CLI, just type `git log` and look at the last entry.

Answer (score 12):

This is the command you were looking for:

```
git log --pretty=tformat:"%h" -n1 .
```

Note: "." is the current directory, you may want to specify a specific directory instead.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Schlacki answer

If you need the full commit hash rather than the short hash you can do this.

`git log --pretty=tformat:"%H" -n1 .`

Not capital H rather than lower case h